# How to make an application page accessible to all users?

Tags: permissions, application-pages

We are using SP2013, and have created an application page (policy.aspx), deployed via VS into layouts folder. Our environment has 1 web app with multiple site collections. The policy page should be accessible to all users.

At moment we have hardcoded the path of the policy page to sitecol1_layouts\test\policy.aspx and notice that suppose USER A tries to access this page from sitecol1 then he can access because he is member of this site col. However, if User B (member of sitecol2) tries to access this path then he gets error, however, a solution to this is to dynamically generate the current site URL and then appends the _layouts\test\policy.aspx to it.

Now, this works, I want to know if this is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/_Layouts/` represents the physical path and is accessible from any site / site collection. So if you are using Javascript client object model it can be retrieved using `SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl` . Example:

```
var pageUrl = SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('/SharePointRibbonDemo/RibbonDemo.aspx')
```

In server side this can be retrieved using `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS")`

Comment: Is this the only solution? Was my question.

Comment: There may be other ways as well, but I find this to be nice way of doing it instead of hard coding or doing some unnecessary string manipulations and concatenations